# Examples for Lightning Timer Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I've an existing app which heavily uses a custom Visualforce Timer component (usual timer - start/ stop/ reset). We're porting over our application to use Lightning and running into issues porting this into a Lightning Component.

I see there is a component library but I do not find any timer component. Can anyone tell me if there is a built-in/ 3rd party timer component for Lightning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a built-in one, but I was able to create my own fairly simply.

Here is the repo : https://github.com/moshekarmel1/Stopwatch.

I am using a static resource that contains bootstrap, but you really don't have to use that if you don't want to. The main thing is Stopwatch.cmp and StopwatchController.js.