# Salesforce Countdown timer

Tags: apex

I am new to Salesforce and I am trying to implement the below scenario.

I am having Custom object `Timer__c` and is having fields `User__c` to `User` and a `Time` field `Time__c`.
Once I enter time in `Time__c`, lets say 10 seconds and on clicking save, record should get saved and the countdown timer should get started at same time and at the end of 10 seconds, I want to show the popup in service console.
Can anyone help me in implementing the same if possible.

Comment: are you using Classic or lightning?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to use Apex for this. You can directly create a lightning component and use javascript setTimeOut or setInterval to your advantagge.

There is a sample lightning component for timer: 
[Examples for Lightning Timer Component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103844/examples-for-lightning-timer-component)

More about javascript setTimeout : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Hello Pranay, actually my requirement is pretty different here, on clicking save button the record should get saved and also automatically timer should start in the background and at the end of timer, a pop up should come. I am not going to work on any buttons rite.

Comment: You have to create records using Apex or lightning data services, but that timer or modal etc has to be javascript. Apex is server side and the UI you want cant be done single handedly with Apex

Comment: If possible, can you help me out with code please.

Comment: This forum is not a code writing service. Please refrain from asking others to provide code samples. Thanks